# Creating a column from the existence of matching rows in an other table?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table **people** and a table **pets** and I'd like to display all people who have pets and all people who don't have pets. A person can have either no pet or any number of pets.

I can use IF EXISTS, but then I have to use two queries:

```
select * from person where exists (select * from pet where person.id = pet.owner)
```

and

```
select * from person where not exists (select * from pet where person.id = pet.owner)
```

Is there a way to combine these in a single query, so that I can have a list of person data with an additional column which says if the person has a pet or not? I don't want to use group by and count, because I don't need the acutal number of pets, only the info if there is a pet, so I want to merge the EXISTS data of the above two queries into an extra boolean column.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative solution**

```
select
    p.*, 
    case when exists
                 (
                    select * 
                    from pets 
                    where personId = p.id
                 )
                 then select 1 
                 else select 0 
                 end
    as HasPets
from person p
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: This looks good, though it gives me a syntax error at the mysql command line. Probably it's a typo on my side, still checking...

Comment: Looks like CASE can only be used in stored procedure, not in simple queries. It's a pity. because it's just what I need, but I don't currently use stored procedures.

Comment: Might be a typo on my side as well, I don't have a mysql installation at hand to try it on.

Comment: You're devil :) - It's the most extraordinary solution i've ever seen. and btw: CASE work in select statements too.

Comment: It really does work with a few syntax changes: select people.*, case when exists ( select * from pets where pets.person = people.id) then 1 else 0 end as has_pet from people;

Comment: Great! I'll modify my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person.*, COUNT(pets.id)>0 AS have_pets FROM person LEFT JOIN pet ON pet.owner=person.id;
```

Comment: Okay, but the COUNT statement counts all the matching rows and this is exactly what I want to avoid with EXISTS which stops dealing with further matches of the same owner after the first matching row.

Comment: But thanks to the combination of the left join and the clause that count must be above 0 it actually gives you the result you need (count(pets.id)>0 will either give true or false (or 1 or 0))